# Modify existing javascript to only output the first value in an array within google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have no background in Javascript at all, but I've found myself needing to use it (I think).

What I'm trying to do is to automatically pull data (most common translation) into a google docs spreadsheet from Jisho.org, based on an English word I enter into a google form.
The outcome will hopefully be a quick way to generate  EN>JP translations for later study.

This is the current process with the default script:

1. Enter English word into form.
2. [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YmZnMvF_APf-iFo5JIVj14bsTAprqKpaueAfQ6bhflo/edit?usp=sharing) creates [a link](http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=%23words%20%23common%20Last%20Year) to fetch data from website.
3. Spreadsheet then populates an array using the script below.
4. Array prevents the next word from doing its thing because it takes up multiple rows.
5. Errors

Now, what I want it to do is only return the top most value, instead of it showing all of them.

I've been tweaking with the js code a bit and I've managed to get it to not create extra rows by changing rowIndex to 0 or 1 in different places (probably 100% the wrong thing to do, but I've got no clue), but what that also did was make the cell with the formula in it become the last value in the list because they overwrite each other.

I've tried looking at similar questions on here, but I don't know enough about Javascript to be able to adapt any of the other outcomes, due to most of them use a very different structure to the one I found.

I tried using =importXML() in the spreadsheet, while it 'worked', it causes the whole thing to freeze up and inevitably crash if you go over 10 words and each word takes multiple minutes to populate.

So, is it possible to do what I'm after with this script? Is there a better way? Should I be using something completely different?

Thanks

```
    /*====================================================================================================================================*
  ImportJSON by Trevor Lohrbeer (@FastFedora)
  ====================================================================================================================================
  Version:      1.2.1
  Project Page: http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json
  Copyright:    (c) 2012-2013 by Trevor Lohrbeer
  License:      GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPL-3.0) 
                http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A library for importing JSON feeds into Google spreadsheets. Functions include:

     ImportJSON            For use by end users to import a JSON feed from a URL 
     ImportJSONViaPost     For use by end users to import a JSON feed from a URL using POST parameters
     ImportJSONAdvanced    For use by script developers to easily extend the functionality of this library

  Future enhancements may include:

   - Support for a real XPath like syntax similar to ImportXML for the query parameter
   - Support for OAuth authenticated APIs (see AddOAuthService__ function for failed experiment)

  Or feel free to write these and add on to the library yourself!
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Changelog:

  1.2.1  Fixed a bug with how nested arrays are handled. The rowIndex counter wasn't incrementing properly when parsing.
  1.2.0  Added ImportJSONViaPost and support for fetchOptions to ImportJSONAdvanced
  1.1.1  Added a version number using Google Scripts Versioning so other developers can use the library
  1.1    Added support for the noHeaders option
  1.0    Initial release
 *====================================================================================================================================*/
/**
 * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
 * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
 * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
 * 
 * By default, data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *      of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content",
 *               "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
 * 
 * @param {url}          the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {query}        a comma-separated list of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
 * @param {parseOptions} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions) {
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, null, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}

/**
 * Imports a JSON feed via a POST request and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is 
 * flattened to create a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to 
 * that data in the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data.
 *
 * To retrieve the JSON, a POST request is sent to the URL and the payload is passed as the content of the request using the content 
 * type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If the fetchOptions define a value for "method", "payload" or "contentType", these 
 * values will take precedent. For example, advanced users can use this to make this function pass XML as the payload using a GET 
 * request and a content type of "application/xml; charset=utf-8". For more information on the available fetch options, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app . At this time the "headers" option is not supported.
 * 
 * By default, the returned data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "user=bob&apikey=xxxx", 
 *               "validateHttpsCertificates=false", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
 * 
 * @param {url}          the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {payload}      the content to pass with the POST request; usually a URL encoded list of parameters separated by ampersands
 * @param {fetchOptions} a comma-separated list of options used to retrieve the JSON feed from the URL
 * @param {query}        a comma-separated list of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
 * @param {parseOptions} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSONViaPost(url, payload, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions) {
  var postOptions = parseToObject_(fetchOptions);

  if (postOptions["method"] == null) {
    postOptions["method"] = "POST";
  }

  if (postOptions["payload"] == null) {
    postOptions["payload"] = payload;
  }

  if (postOptions["contentType"] == null) {
    postOptions["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  convertToBool_(postOptions, "validateHttpsCertificates");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "useIntranet");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "followRedirects");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "muteHttpExceptions");

  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, postOptions, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}

/**
 * An advanced version of ImportJSON designed to be easily extended by a script. This version cannot be called from within a 
 * spreadsheet.
 * 
 * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
 * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
 * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
 *
 * The fetchOptions can be used to change how the JSON feed is retrieved. For instance, the "method" and "payload" options can be 
 * set to pass a POST request with post parameters. For more information on the available parameters, see 
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app .
 *
 * Use the include and transformation functions to determine what to include in the import and how to transform the data after it is
 * imported. 
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", 
 *              new Object() { "method" : "post", "payload" : "user=bob&apikey=xxxx" },
 *              "/feed/entry",
 *              "",
 *              function (query, path) { return path.indexOf(query) == 0; },
 *              function (data, row, column) { data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 100); } )
 *
 * In this example, the import function checks to see if the path to the data being imported starts with the query. The transform 
 * function takes the data and truncates it. For more robust versions of these functions, see the internal code of this library.
 *
 * @param {url}           the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {fetchOptions}  an object whose properties are options used to retrieve the JSON feed from the URL
 * @param {query}         the query passed to the include function
 * @param {parseOptions}  a comma-separated list of options that may alter processing of the data
 * @param {includeFunc}   a function with the signature func(query, path, options) that returns true if the data element at the given path
 *                        should be included or false otherwise. 
 * @param {transformFunc} a function with the signature func(data, row, column, options) where data is a 2-dimensional array of the data 
 *                        and row & column are the current row and column being processed. Any return value is ignored. Note that row 0 
 *                        contains the headers for the data, so test for row==0 to process headers only.
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {

  Logger.log('test log');

  //url = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/27075655?begIndex=15&endIndex=30&queue=0&queue=2&queue=4&queue=6&queue=7&queue=8&queue=9&queue=14&queue=16&queue=17&queue=25&queue=31&queue=32&queue=33&queue=41&queue=42&queue=52&queue=61&queue=65&queue=70&queue=73&queue=76&queue=78&queue=83&queue=91&queue=92&queue=93&queue=96&queue=98&queue=300";
  //url = "https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/27075655";
  /*
  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Vapor eyJkYXRlX3RpbWUiOjE0MzQxMzM0MjUsImdhc19hY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiMjcwNzU2NTUiLCJwdnBuZXRfYWNjb3VudF9pZCI6IjI3MDc1NjU1Iiwic3VtbW9uZXJfbmFtZSI6ImF0aGFjZSIsInZvdWNoaW5nX2tleV9pZCI6IjkwMzQ3NTJiMmI0NTYwNDRhZTg3ZjI1OTgyZGFkMDdkIiwic2lnbmF0dXJlIjoiUFc5bUdJOU5pU3VwaituQ1MyNm9RaVVQelRRTmJaY0RhOXRaUzl2TlR2RDVVdnJXNWRZUlVFZjVOVmw3TWZ3QVYzUW4rOHUrRWFFWWlUemFKeFMzUkdrSzRyYjdmckhrSzkxRXI3K1V6R1ZGZEJlc3lJSjQ0am1uT1pUVGxJNUdvRktLTW5CbkhReENYNkdaY295Z3dHTFRyV2w3MW5tNU0wVUtxQUNoaFBNPSJ9",
    "Region" : "EUNE"
    };

  fetchOptions =
   {
     "method" : "get",
     "headers" : headers
   };
   */

  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  //var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/207378793", fetchOptions);

  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  //var object   = JSON.parse("{\"champions\":[{\"id\":266,\"active\":true,\"freeToPlay\":false},{\"id\":103,\"active\":true,\"freeToPlay\":false},{\"id\":143,\"active\":true,\"freeToPlay\":false}]}");

  //var url = "{\"name\" : [\"x\",\"z\"]}";
  //var object   = JSON.parse(url);

  //var object   = JSON.parse("{\"champions\":{\"atti\":{\"id\":266,\"active\":true,\"freeToPlay\":false},\"vivi\":{\"id\":103,\"active\":true,\"freeToPlay\":false}}}");

  //var jsonstr = "[   {       \"id\":\"123\"    },   {       \"id\":\"457\",      \"jobs\": [         {            \"rate\":\"5.45\"         },         {            \"rate\":\"5.75\",            \"country\":\"US\"         }      ]   },   {      \"id\":\"458\",      \"jobs\": [         {            \"rate\":\"5.55\",            \"feedback\":               {                  \"score\":\"5.0\"               }         }      ]   }]";
  //var object = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

  //query = "/champions/atti/id,/champions/atti/active";

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc, url);
}

/** 
 * Encodes the given value to use within a URL.
 *
 * @param {value} the value to be encoded
 * 
 * @return the value encoded using URL percent-encoding
 */
function URLEncode(value) {
  return encodeURIComponent(value.toString());  
}

/**
 * Adds an oAuth service using the given name and the list of properties.
 *
 * @note This method is an experiment in trying to figure out how to add an oAuth service without having to specify it on each 
 *       ImportJSON call. The idea was to call this method in the first cell of a spreadsheet, and then use ImportJSON in other
 *       cells. This didn't work, but leaving this in here for further experimentation later. 
 *
 *       The test I did was to add the following into the A1:
 *  
 *           =AddOAuthService("twitter", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
 *                            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
 *                            "<my consumer key>", "<my consumer secret>", "", "")
 *
 *       Information on obtaining a consumer key & secret for Twitter can be found at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth
 *
 *       Then I added the following into A2:
 *
 *           =ImportJSONViaPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=fastfedora&count=2", "",
 *                              "oAuthServiceName=twitter,oAuthUseToken=always", "/", "")
 *
 *       I received an error that the "oAuthServiceName" was not a valid value. [twl 18.Apr.13]
 */
function AddOAuthService__(name, accessTokenUrl, requestTokenUrl, authorizationUrl, consumerKey, consumerSecret, method, paramLocation) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);

  if (accessTokenUrl != null && accessTokenUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(accessTokenUrl);
  }

  if (requestTokenUrl != null && requestTokenUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(requestTokenUrl);
  }

  if (authorizationUrl != null && authorizationUrl.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(authorizationUrl);
  }

  if (consumerKey != null && consumerKey.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  }

  if (consumerSecret != null && consumerSecret.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  }

  if (method != null && method.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setMethod(method);
  }

  if (paramLocation != null && paramLocation.length > 0) {
    oAuthConfig.setParamLocation(paramLocation);
  }
}

/** 
 * Parses a JSON object and returns a two-dimensional array containing the data of that object.
 */
function parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc, url) {
  var headers = new Array();
  var data    = new Array();

  // athace
  if(hasOption_(options, "debugURL")) {
    data[1] = new Array();
    data[1][6] = url;
  }

  if (query && !Array.isArray(query) && query.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
    query = query.toString().split(",");
  }

  if (options) {
    options = options.toString().split(",");
  }

  parseData_(headers, data, "", {rowIndex: 1}, object, query, options, includeFunc);
  parseHeaders_(headers, data);
  transformData_(data, options, transformFunc);

  return hasOption_(options, "noHeaders") ? (data.length > 1 ? data.slice(1) : new Array()) : data;
}

/** 
 * Parses the data contained within the given value and inserts it into the data two-dimensional array starting at the rowIndex. 
 * If the data is to be inserted into a new column, a new header is added to the headers array. The value can be an object, 
 * array or scalar value.
 *
 * If the value is an object, it's properties are iterated through and passed back into this function with the name of each 
 * property extending the path. For instance, if the object contains the property "entry" and the path passed in was "/feed",
 * this function is called with the value of the entry property and the path "/feed/entry".
 *
 * If the value is an array containing other arrays or objects, each element in the array is passed into this function with 
 * the rowIndex incremeneted for each element.
 *
 * If the value is an array containing only scalar values, those values are joined together and inserted into the data array as 
 * a single value.
 *
 * If the value is a scalar, the value is inserted directly into the data array.
 */
function parseData_(headers, data, path, state, value, query, options, includeFunc) {
  var dataInserted = false;

  if (Array.isArray(value) && isObjectArray_(value)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (parseData_(headers, data, path, state, value[i], query, options, includeFunc)) {
        dataInserted = true;

        // athace:
        //if (i > 0 && data[state.rowIndex]) {
        if (i > -1 && data[state.rowIndex] && i < value.length - 1) {
          state.rowIndex++;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (isObject_(value)) {
    for (key in value) {
      if (parseData_(headers, data, path + "/" + key, state, value[key], query, options, includeFunc)) {
        dataInserted = true; 
      }
    }

    // athace: Break line after the actual values
    if (hasOption_(options, "champions") && data[state.rowIndex]) {
          state.rowIndex++;
    }
  } else if (!includeFunc || (includeFunc(query, path, options) == !hasOption_(options, "excludeQuery"))) {
    // Handle arrays containing only scalar values
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value = value.join(); 
    }

    // Insert new row if one doesn't already exist
    if (!data[state.rowIndex]) {
      data[state.rowIndex] = new Array();
    }

    // athace: Remove the actual path
    if (hasOption_(options, "champions")) {
      path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length);
    }

    // Add a new header if one doesn't exist
    if (!headers[path] && headers[path] != 0) {
      headers[path] = Object.keys(headers).length;
    }

    // Insert the data
    data[state.rowIndex][headers[path]] = value;
    dataInserted = true;
  }

  return dataInserted;
}

/** 
 * Parses the headers array and inserts it into the first row of the data array.
 */
function parseHeaders_(headers, data) {
  data[0] = new Array();

  for (key in headers) {
    data[0][headers[key]] = key;
  }
}

/** 
 * Applies the transform function for each element in the data array, going through each column of each row.
 */
function transformData_(data, options, transformFunc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      transformFunc(data, i, j, options);
    }
  }
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given test value is an object; false otherwise.
 */
function isObject_(test) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(test) === '[object Object]';
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given test value is an array containing at least one object; false otherwise.
 */
function isObjectArray_(test) {
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (isObject_(test[i])) {
      return true; 
    }
  }  

  return false;
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given query applies to the given path. 
 */
function includeXPath_(query, path, options) {
  if (!query) {
    return true; 
  } else if (Array.isArray(query)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      if (applyXPathRule_(query[i], path, options)) {
        return true;
      }
    }  
  } else {
    return applyXPathRule_(query, path, options);
  }

  return false; 
};

/** 
 * Returns true if the rule applies to the given path. 
 */
function applyXPathRule_(rule, path, options) {
  return path.indexOf(rule) == 0; 
}

/** 
 * By default, this function transforms the value at the given row & column so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Values in row 0 (headers) have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title 
*      case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 */
function defaultTransform_(data, row, column, options) {
  // athace: fix to issues with 0 values
  //if (!data[row][column]) {
  if (data[row][column] == null) {
    if (row < 2 || hasOption_(options, "noInherit")) {
      data[row][column] = "";
    } else {
      data[row][column] = data[row-1][column];
    }
  } 

  if (!hasOption_(options, "rawHeaders") && row == 0) {
    if (column == 0 && data[row].length > 1) {
      removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row);  
    }

    data[row][column] = toTitleCase_(data[row][column].toString().replace(/[\/\_]/g, " "));
  }

  if (!hasOption_(options, "noTruncate") && data[row][column]) {
    data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 256);
  }

  if (hasOption_(options, "debugLocation")) {
    data[row][column] = "[" + row + "," + column + "]" + data[row][column];
  }

  // athace
  if (hasOption_(options, "parseNumbers")) {
    var num = filterFloat(data[row][column]);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      data[row][column] = num;
    }
  }
}

// athace
function filterFloat(value) {
  if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/.test(value)) {
    return Number(value);
  }
  return NaN;
}


/** 
 * If all the values in the given row share the same prefix, remove that prefix.
 */
function removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row) {
  var matchIndex = data[row][0].length;

  for (var i = 1; i < data[row].length; i++) {
    matchIndex = findEqualityEndpoint_(data[row][i-1], data[row][i], matchIndex);

    if (matchIndex == 0) {
      return;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < data[row].length; i++) {
    data[row][i] = data[row][i].substring(matchIndex, data[row][i].length);
  }
}

/** 
 * Locates the index where the two strings values stop being equal, stopping automatically at the stopAt index.
 */
function findEqualityEndpoint_(string1, string2, stopAt) {
  if (!string1 || !string2) {
    return -1; 
  }

  var maxEndpoint = Math.min(stopAt, string1.length, string2.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < maxEndpoint; i++) {
    if (string1.charAt(i) != string2.charAt(i)) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return maxEndpoint;
}


/** 
 * Converts the text to title case.
 */
function toTitleCase_(text) {
  if (text == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return text.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(word) { return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

/** 
 * Returns true if the given set of options contains the given option.
 */
function hasOption_(options, option) {
  return options && options.indexOf(option) >= 0;
}

/** 
 * Parses the given string into an object, trimming any leading or trailing spaces from the keys.
 */
function parseToObject_(text) {
  var map     = new Object();
  var entries = (text != null && text.trim().length > 0) ? text.toString().split(",") : new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    addToMap_(map, entries[i]);  
  }

  return map;
}

/** 
 * Parses the given entry and adds it to the given map, trimming any leading or trailing spaces from the key.
 */
function addToMap_(map, entry) {
  var equalsIndex = entry.indexOf("=");  
  var key         = (equalsIndex != -1) ? entry.substring(0, equalsIndex) : entry;
  var value       = (key.length + 1 < entry.length) ? entry.substring(key.length + 1) : "";

  map[key.trim()] = value;
}

/** 
 * Returns the given value as a boolean.
 */
function toBool_(value) {
  return value == null ? false : (value.toString().toLowerCase() == "true" ? true : false);
}

/**
 * Converts the value for the given key in the given map to a bool.
 */
function convertToBool_(map, key) {
  if (map[key] != null) {
    map[key] = toBool_(map[key]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: usually you don't modify libraries, but of course you can. Usually you would write a script which utilizes the library and makes the necessary modifications to the libraries output.

Comment: I can only see one instance in this code where `rowIndex` has a number attached to it, and it is the number `1`. Didn't you say you made it into `0` or `1` depending on the context? is this all the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don't modify libraries, but of course you can. Usually you would write a script which utilizes the library and makes the necessary modifications to the libraries output.

However, if the overwriting problem is your only one, and if I understand this code correctly (glanced over it), you could try this:

at the top of the file add

```
var wroteValue = false;
```

and then at the top of `parseData_` function (just above `var dataInserted = false;`), add this:

```
if (wroteValue) return false; // could also try true
```

and then instead of this in that function

```
// Insert the data
data[state.rowIndex][headers[path]] = value;
```

put

```
if (!wroteValue) {
    // Insert the data
    data[state.rowIndex][headers[path]] = value;
    wroteValue = true;
}
```

this should make it only put the `value` once. This is a long long shot, and not very pretty coding, and could be inefficient (take a long time) but you can let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you, that made it do what I was after.